# Iterating through xml file

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to get all surnames from xml file, but if I am trying to use find, It throws an exception

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

This is my code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for elem in root:
    for subelem in elem:
        for subsubelem in subelem.find('surname'):
             print(subsubelem.text)
```

When I remove the `find('surname')` from code, It returning all texts from subsubelements.

This is xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pp:card xmlns:pp="http://xmlns.page.com/path/subpath">
    <pp:id>1</pp:id>
    <pp:customers>
        <pp:customer>
            <pp:name>John</pp:name>
            <pp:surname>Walker</pp:surname>
            <pp:adress>
                <pp:street>Walker street</pp:street>
                <pp:number>1/1</pp:number>
                <pp:state>England</pp:state>
            </pp:adress>
            <pp:created>2021-03-08Z</pp:created>
        </pp:customer>
        <pp:customer>
            <pp:name>Michael</pp:name>
            <pp:surname>Jordan</pp:surname>
            <pp:adress>
                <pp:street>Jordan street</pp:street>
                <pp:number>28</pp:number>
                <pp:state>USA</pp:state>
            </pp:adress>
            <pp:created>2021-03-09Z</pp:created>
        </pp:customer>
    </pp:customers>
</pp:card>
```

How should I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Not really a python person, but should the "find" statement include the "pp:" in its search, such as,

```
find('pp:surname')
```

Neither the opening nor closing tags actually match "surname".

Answer (score 0):

Use the namespace when you call findall

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pp:card xmlns:pp="http://xmlns.page.com/path/subpath">
    <pp:id>1</pp:id>
    <pp:customers>
        <pp:customer>
            <pp:name>John</pp:name>
            <pp:surname>Walker</pp:surname>
            <pp:adress>
                <pp:street>Walker street</pp:street>
                <pp:number>1/1</pp:number>
                <pp:state>England</pp:state>
            </pp:adress>
            <pp:created>2021-03-08Z</pp:created>
        </pp:customer>
        <pp:customer>
            <pp:name>Michael</pp:name>
            <pp:surname>Jordan</pp:surname>
            <pp:adress>
                <pp:street>Jordan street</pp:street>
                <pp:number>28</pp:number>
                <pp:state>USA</pp:state>
            </pp:adress>
            <pp:created>2021-03-09Z</pp:created>
        </pp:customer>
    </pp:customers>
</pp:card>'''

ns = {'pp': 'http://xmlns.page.com/path/subpath'}
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
names = [sn.text for sn in root.findall('.//pp:surname', ns)]
print(names)
```

output

```
['Walker', 'Jordan']
```